# Using [] on pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers, indexing

Right now I'm looking over some C code and they have some pointer syntax that I'm confused about. So first they declared a pointer like so:

```
int32_t *p_tx_buf=NULL;
```

Then later on they wrote:

```
p_tx_buf = malloc(...math... );
```

The stuff in the middle is just math to calculate the size of a file, I'm assuming it's not important. After that, they wrote:

```
p_tx_buf[0] = 0
```

I'm rather confused about the `[]`. How does that work with an integer pointer? I thought the `[]` was for indexing things, so I'm confused on how you can use this with a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C (and also C++), `array[n]` is equivalent to `*(array+n)`. They mean exactly the same thing and produce exactly the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`p_tx_buf[0] = 0` means assign `0` to the location `p_tx_buf + 0`.

Comment: Do you mean ... "to the location `*(p_tx_buf + 0)`"  ?

Comment: @ryyker; No. I mean `p_tx_buf + 0` like `int x ; x = 0;` you are writing at location `&x`. `*(p_tx_buf + 0)` will be used to dereference that value from  `p_tx_buf + 0` location.

Comment: If `p_tx_buf[0]` is equivalent to '*(p_tx_buf + 0)`... then `p_tx_buf[0] = 0` would also be equivalent to '*(p_tx_buf + 0) = 0`

Comment: @ryyker; Yeah, that's true. But the location would be `p_tx_buf + 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expound a bit on the answers already provided, the "math" you are referring to is probably not calculating the size of a *single* file, rather it is multiplying the size of a file times some integer.

The result is that enough space is allocated for *several* file structures. The pointer winds up pointing to the first of several file structures laid out sequentially in memory. The index `[0]` means point to the first of those file structures (i.e., an *offset* of 0)

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't expand on that, I just didn't think it was necessary to the question. But yeah, the math basically multiplies the size of a "block" of data with how many blocks are in the file, so what you said is definitely true.

Comment: Then that would be the reason that the array notation was used. If only a single object was allocated, the author would be more likely to use pointer notation.

Answer (score 1):

the malloc command I assume was some multiplication of the sizeof(int32_t)

say:

```
p_tx_buf = malloc(2*sizeof(int32_t));
```

you now have allocated enough memory space for 2 int32_t variables you can access them by:

```
*(p_tx_buf) and *(p_tx_buf+1)
```

or

```
p_tx_buf[0] and p_tx_buf[1]
```

Comment: No, arrays are not "essentially pointers". Please read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). An expressions of array type is implicitly *converted*, in most but not all contexts, to a pointer to the array's initial element.

Comment: @KeithThompson you are right.  I removed that wording